# Git rebase develop before merging to develop?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

is it supposed to be a good practise to always rebase the develop branch back into my feature/ branch before merging my feature/ branch back into develop?

Comment: do you merge it with --no-ff then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only if

- you didn't push your feature branch currently being developed,
- of you did push but nobody else is using it and it is ok to push --force once rebased

But generally, yes, it is a good idea to rebase first and resolve conflicts locally, in order to have a feature developed on top of the latest of `develop`.

Comment: Hi VonC,
what does the push have to do with the decision?

Comment: @lockdoc because a rebase is likely to change the SHA1 of your commits: if others have already pulled from your branch, changing its history will force them to reset their branch to your new history.

Comment: so would you say a git merge of develop into my feature branch is generally better during development?

Comment: @lockdoc no: if you haven't push or if you are the only one to push, a rebase is better, as it keep the history linear (no merge commit)

Comment: But what if multiple people work on this feature branch and it is required to push it on a regular base. What would be the best practise here?

Comment: @lockdoc the a simple git pull (fetch + merge) is recommended.

Comment: I accept this as the answer, because it simply answers the question well. Unfortunately for me, there are even more questions now than before. Maybe you could recommend a good link to read up about rebase and remote branches.

Comment: @lockdoc Sure: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase/, https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/, https://www.atlassian.com/git/articles/git-team-workflows-merge-or-rebase/, https://medium.com/@porteneuve/getting-solid-at-git-rebase-vs-merge-4fa1a48c53aa

Answer (score 0):

If there are conflicts while merging `feature` branch into `develop`, then rebase can be an alternative to merging `develop` into `feature` or resolving the conflucts while merging `feature` into `develop` (beware the issue described by VonC though). If `feature` merges into `develop` without conflicts, then I don't see any good reason to rebase - just go ahead and merge.